# Overriding parent class's function

Tags: c++, class, function, overriding

```
class classa {
public:
    virtual void foo();
};

class classb : public classa {
public:
     virtual void foo() override;
};


void classa::foo()
{
    std::cout << "foo from a" << std::endl;
}

void classb::foo()
{
    std::cout << "foo from b" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<classa> stuff; 

    classa a;
    classb b;

    stuff.push_back(a);
    stuff.push_back(b);

    stuff[0].foo();
    stuff[1].foo();


    return 0;
}
```

I expected the above code to return

```
foo from a 
foo from b
```

but it returns both as `foo from a`.

I think this is because the vector stores `classa` but I am not sure. 
How can I get `classb:foo()` to be called by `b`?

Comment: "std::cout stuff;" seems wrong, are you sure that's really your code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c

Comment: @PeteFordham stackoverflow changed it for some reason. It is meant to read (this might change too...): std::vector<classa> stuff;

Comment: You can't use `<` and `>` in a `<pre>` because it is interpreted as HTML. Instead, use four space indenting.

Comment: What version of C++ contains the `override` keyword?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens because of **object slicing**, you'll need to keep a vector of pointers (preferably smart pointers).

I'm assuming `stuff` is defined as `std::vector<classa> stuff;`. When you do

```
stuff.push_back(b);
```

the object pushed into the vector is a slice of `b` - particulary the `classa` part. All other type info is lost. For this to work as expected, you'd need:

```
std::vector<classa*> stuff;
```

or similar. The way your code is now, you can't get it to work because `stuff[1]` is no longer a `classb`, but a `classa`.

Comment: I have to use `stuff.push_back(&a);`. That is right, right?

Comment: @andrew either that, or create the object with `new` (and `delete` it afterwards).